# Facebook Open Graph Submit Action

Tags: magento, facebook-opengraph

> Hello Facebook Masters,
>
> I am using Facebook Open Graph application for my magento site.
>
> For this we need to create one application in facebook and we need to
>   add buttons like, want, wish etc. Thats all fine I have created the
>   buttons as well. But we have to approve that button from facebook. we
>   need to post the product url for making approval submition for the
>   want button
>
> i am not able to post the product url. Please help me..
>
> Here is my code used for posting the url :
>
> http://ogp.me/ns#
>   zoomin-magento:http://ogp.me/ns/apps/zoomin-magento#">   OG
>   Tutorial App
>
> function postCook()   {
>         FB.api(
>           '/me/zoomin-magento:want',
>           'post',
>           { product: 'http://camera.zoomin.com/camera-phones-1/sony-ericsson-xperia-ray-st18i.html'
>   },
>           function(response) {
>              if (!response || response.error) {
>                 alert('Error occured');
>              } else {
>                 alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
>              }
>           });   }           
>       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>         FB.init({
>           appId      : '368510486563356', // App ID
>           status     : true, // check login status
>           cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
>           xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
>         });
>       };
>
> ```
> // Load the SDK Asynchronously
> (function(d){
>   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
>   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
>   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
>   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
> }(document));   </script>
> ```
>
> #### Stuffed Cookies

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained why you cannot share the URL. Nevertheless, for circumstances where the approval team cannot see the app, you can make a video of the app in actions, demonstrating the action being taken, and submit that.

Also check the doc @ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/

Comment: that problem is being solved but now other problem is there, after making all the configuration in the admin of magento when i click on the want button on my product page, i got following error: [Facebook error: The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified:Product]

Comment: The POST must include the URL of a product object your user is acting on. That's the error you'd see if you'd omitted it.

Comment: Hello James, Can you please tell me how can i post the action using Graph API Explorer? i have spent too much time on this issue. please Help me....!!!!

Comment: make sure Graph Explorer has the publish_actions permission, then create a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/me/namespace:action_name with a body containing object_name=http://mydomain.com/myobject

Comment: obviously replace namespace, action_name, object_name and the URL according to your app